# Would JRebel work with this project setup?

Tags: jrebel

we have a project where we use Maven to deploy to Tomcat on mvn clean install. I'm fairly new to Java development and finding it difficult to continually wait for install to complete to view changes. I use IntelliJ and I think the class files are only created during mvn install in the target directory.

Is it possible to use JRebel so when I save a file in IntelliJ the compiled class updates Tomcat immediately like they show on the JRebel video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ saves the file automatically for you. All you need to do is to recompile the changed classes and these will be picked up by JRebel, given you have included rebel.xml configuration file into the deployed archive.